# Using QuickCheck to Verify Free Monad's Functor Instance

Tags: haskell

Given the `Free Monad`, and my `Eq`, `Show`, and `Functor` instances, I attempted to verify the first `Functor` law using QuickCheck:

```
data Free f a = Var a
               | Node (f (Free f a))
```

I defined the following `Eq` and `Show` instances (credit to [duplode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32675520/409976) for helping me out on the `Eq` instance:

```
instance (Eq (f (Free f a)), Eq a) => Eq (Free f a) where
    (==) (Var x) (Var y)       = x == y
    (==) (Node fu1) (Node fu2) = fu1 == fu2
    (==) _ _                   = False

instance (Show (f (Free f a)), Show a) => Show (Free f a) where
  show (Var x)  = "Var " ++ (show x)
  show (Node x) = "Node " ++ (show x)
```

Then, I implemented a `Functor` instance:

```
instance Functor f => Functor (Free f) where
  fmap g (Var x)  = Var (g x)
  fmap g (Node x) = Node $ fmap (\y -> fmap g y) x
```

And now the QuickCheck work:

```
instance Arbitrary (Free Maybe Int) where
    arbitrary = do
        x <- arbitrary :: Gen Int
        y <- arbitrary :: Gen Int
        elements [Var x, Var y, Node (Nothing), Node (Just (Var y))] 

--fmap id = id

functor_id_law ::  Free Maybe Int -> Bool
functor_id_law x = (fmap id x) == (id x)
```

Finally, run it in QuickCheck:

```
ghci> quickCheck functor_id_law 
+++ OK, passed 100 tests.
```

However, I haven't included other `Functor`'s, such as `[]`, etc. Nor have I used other types, i.e. `Char`, `String`, etc.

What's a more rigorous approach to verifying that my definition of the `Free Monad`'s `Functor` instance obeys the first Functor Law?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Use Eq1 to implement Eq, Show1 to implement Show

While [it's a very recent addition](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.0.0/docs/Data-Functor-Classes.html), you should implement `Eq` via `Eq1` and `Show` via `Show1`. That removes the `UndecidableInstances` pragma from your code:

```
import Data.Functor.Classes

data Free f a = Var a
               | Node (f (Free f a)) 

instance (Eq1 f) => Eq1 (Free f) where
  liftEq f (Var x)    (Var y)    = f x y
  liftEq f (Node fu1) (Node fu2) = liftEq (liftEq f) fu1 fu2
  liftEq _ _ _                   = False

instance (Eq1 f, Eq a) => Eq (Free f a) where
  (==) = eq1


instance Show1 f => Show1 (Free f) where
  liftShowsPrec sp sl = go
    where
      go d (Var a) = showsUnaryWith sp "Var" d a
      go d (Node fa) = showsUnaryWith (liftShowsPrec go (liftShowList sp sl)) "Node" d fa

instance (Show1 f, Show a) => Show (Free f a) where
  showsPrec = showsPrec1
```

We need to lift twice: once through the functor `f`, and once through the next `Free`.

## QuickCheck

Your instance isn't very flexible. Furthermore, QuickCheck cannot set its size. Instead of a fixed size, use `sized`:

```
instance Arbitrary (Free Maybe Int) where
    arbitrary = sized go
      where
        go 0 = Var <$> arbitrary
        go n = Node <$> oneof [pure Nothing, Just <$> go (n - 1)]
```

However, that only yields a single instance. As with `Show` and `Eq`, there exists an [`Arbitrary1`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck-2.11.3/docs/Test-QuickCheck-Arbitrary.html#t:Arbitrary1) class we can use instead:

```
instance Arbitrary1 f => Arbitrary1 (Free f) where
  liftArbitrary a = sized (go . min 3)
    where
      go 0 = Var <$> a
      go n = Node <$> liftArbitrary (go (n - 1))

instance (Arbitrary1 f, Arbitrary a) => Arbitrary (Free f a) where
  arbitrary = arbitrary1
```

We can now check the functor `id` law easily for many combinations.

## The more rigorous approach

The more rigorous approach with functor laws is to proof them by hand. So let us assume that functor laws hold for the functor `f` in `Free f a`. Then we have to show that

```
fmap id value = value
```

for any `value :: Free f a`. There are two cases. Either `value` is a `Var x` for some `x :: a`. Then

```
fmap id value = fmap id (Var x) = Var (id x) = Var x = value
```

and the law holds. Or `value` is a `Node y` for some `y :: f (Free f a)`. Then

```
fmap id value = fmap id (Node y) 
              = Node (fmap id y)
              = Node (id y)      -- used functor law for `f'
              = Node y
              = value
```

Therefore, the first functor law holds for your instance.